# Cómo instalar la gem de sass en un directorio específico en Windows

Tags: css, ruby, sass

Alguien sabe como instalar la gem de sass en un directorio específico en el sistema operativo Windows.

Hay algún comando?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Como se menciona en la [documentación](https://sass-lang.com/install), descarga el paquete para windows desde su repositorio en [github](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/tag/1.9.0) extraelo en el directorio que deseas y luego agregalo a tu `PATH` en las variables de Windows según se indica [aquí](https://katiek2.github.io/path-doc/)